# How to use tor exit node and VPN to break through GFW in China?

Tags: configuration, exit-relays, vpn, censorship, network-configuration

I am trying to deploy private tor network in China. This whole private tor network is unconnected with the Tor on the Internet. Due to GFW in China, I can only visit domestic internet via my private tor network. So I bought a VPS server in HongKong and deployed VPN server on this VPS and deployed VPN client on my tor exit node. Considering communication between exit node and Dir server, I am trying to use this script([freedom-routes](https://github.com/SaberSalv/freedom-routes)) to route all oversea network flow to VPN. Domestic network accessing directly. However, although domestic network accessing works fine, I can't still visit oversea internet through my own tor network. The question is how can I configure tor exit node or VPN client to route all oversea network flow to my VPN channel. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Would it make your life easier to just run 2 exit nodes: 1 that exits to China only and never uses the VPN, and 1 that exits to everywhere else and always uses the VPN?

Comment: I suspect that a few people in China have already read this and are doing something about it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Tor, but I suppose you just want to go through the GFW in China with a VPS server.(Hong Kong Server is ok)

Most people in China nowadays use SS(shadowsocks)/SSR/V2ray to get thorugh the GFW with VPS. 
I found a link here, about how to install SSR on your VPS.
https://www.tipsforchina.com/how-to-setup-a-fast-shadowsocks-server-on-vultr-vps-the-easy-way.html

SS is same to that, and if you use bandwagon, it has SS/SSR server as default option in KiwiVM.

Some related links: https://www.v2ray.com/
https://shadowsocks.org/en/index.html